# FileInputStream does not work in android widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget, fileinputstream

I've recently found out that I for some reason I can't use FileInputStream on an android widget. Unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution.
Everytime I try I get

> cannot resolve method 'openFileInput(java.lang.string)

Could you help me??

```
try {
        FileInputStream HomeWorkIN = openFileInput(Class + ".txt");
        InputStreamReader HomeWorkREAD = new InputStreamReader(HomeWorkIN);
        char[] data = new char[ReadingBlock];
        String FinalData = "";
        int Size;
        try {
            while ((Size = HomeWorkREAD.read(data)) > 0) {
                String ReadData = String.copyValueOf(data, 0, Size);
                FinalData += ReadData;
                data = new char[ReadingBlock];
            }
            HomeWork += FinalData;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use context.openFileInput

```
FileInputStream HomeWorkIN = context.openFileInput(Class + ".txt");
```